# Include file from dynamic property value

Tags: java, jsp, jspinclude

I have a project in Java thgat needs to use;

```
<%@include file="content.jsp" %>
```

to include a file into the current jsp page.

However, I now need the content.jsp to be dynamic.

How can I substitute everything in the quotes with a variable?

So;

```
<%@include file=myVariable %>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Instead of using static include, you can use dynamic include, then you can do something like this:-

```
<jsp:include page="<%= myVariable %>" flush="true" />
```

or

```
<jsp:include page="${myVariable}" flush="true" />
```

Comment: Ah no.  because I have variables in my main page that need to be accessible from the included page.  I don't get that with <jsp:include

Comment: You can pass parameter in dynamic include using `<jsp:param name="param1" value="value1" />`, couldn't you?

Comment: can you put those variables on the request or the session?

Comment: No I can't put them in the request or the session for reasons only evident to the client.  Just trying out the jsp:param approach now

Comment: @davogotland: That's what I was about to say. :) @griegs: if your variables has string value, then using `jsp:param` is probably the easiest to pass the values. But, if you have objects and such, the easiest is to set store it in the request, then pass the request attribute name using `jsp:param` so that the included page can retrieve the object from request using that parameter.

Comment: @limc these are just string values.

Answer (score 3):

i have work around by using the static include after closing the tag
so it still static and can be used as if you assign a string

```
        <% 

            switch(questionType){

                case 1:%><%@include file="qtypes/yesNo.jspf"%><%
                break; 
                case 5:%><%@include file="qtypes/eval.jspf"%><%
                break; 
                default :%><%@include file="qtypes/yesNo.jspf"%><%
                break; 
            } 

        %>
```

Comment: This is actually a good option. It reduce the risk of JSP include vulnerability. http://find-sec-bugs.github.io/bugs.htm#JSP_INCLUDE