# How do I change the header included in a JSP page based on the value of a session Attribute?

Tags: jsp

Here is my code:

```
<%
 if(session.getAttribute("loggedIn").equals(null))
 {

%>    

<%@ include file="header.jsp"%>

  <%
 }
 else if(session.getAttribute("loggedIn").equals("user"))
 {
    %>

  <%@ include file="pheader.jsp"%>

    <%
 }
    %>
```

This is how I am setting the session attribute:

```
if(utype.equals("admin"))
{
    session.setAttribute("loggedIn", "admin");
}
else 
{
    session.setAttribute("loggedIn", "user");
}
```

This is throwing a null pointer exception.
I understand since nobody is logged in, the attribute value is null.

How do I fix this?

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988086/include-file-from-dynamic-property-value

Comment: Take a variable and if session equals to null or first condition is true then set 'header.jsp' in a variable and if session is not equal to null or second condition is true then set 'pheader.jsp' in a variable. and use like this - <jsp:include page='<%= variablename %>' />..  (Use this jsp:include... line in both condition).

Comment: But, the NullPointerException is in the `if(..)` part. @PuneetChawla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do not use scriptlets in JSP. Use JSTL and EL:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="empty loggedIn">
    <%@ include file="header.jsp"%>
  </c:when>
  <c:when test="loggedIn == 'user'">
    <%@ include file="pheader.jsp"%>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <%-- handle the default case --%>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Second, if you insist on using scriplets, do

```
if (session.getAttribute("loggedIn") == null)
```

instead of

```
if (session.getAttribute("loggedIn").equals(null))
```

as you cannot invoke the `equals` method, if there is no object.

Comment: Hey Thannx! :) Didn't know that thing about the equals() method. And I don't know how to use JSTL and EL. I will try to learn to learn though.

Comment: Hey @Jozef Chocholacek, your answer looks like correct. But can't we do this by using scriplets in JSP?

Comment: @PuneetChawla You can (see the second part of my answer), but you should not: http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/WhyNotUseScriptlets