# Dynamic include JSP

Tags: jsp

i have learned jsp native, i want to include dynamic file. 
i want to call dynamic page using include

**this code**

```
<% String p = request.getParameter("p"); %>

            <%@ include file="pages/"+p+".jsp" %>
```

if i type dashboard.jsp?p=about  the page open "pages/about.jsp"

if i type dashboard.jsp?p=product the page open "pages/product .jsp"

in php this script like this

```
$p= $_GET['p'];
include(pages/'.$p.'.php');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar question
[Include file from dynamic property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988086/include-file-from-dynamic-property-value)

In your case

```
<% String p = request.getParameter("p"); 
   String pagePath = "pages/" + p + ".jsp";
%>

<jsp:include page="<%= pagePath %>" ></jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this code

```
<%String p="pages/"+request.getParameter("p")+".jsp" %>
<jsp:include page="<%=p %>">
</jsp:include>
```

instead of this code

```
<%@ include file="pages/"+p+".jsp" %>
```